# change default component in controller in joomla

Tags: joomla

I am creating a component for joomla.
I have a controller like this

```
class dropdownControllerdropdown extends JControllerForm
{
}
```

the above controller called by this class

```
JToolBarHelper::addNew('dropdown.add');
```

after the controller called that load the dropdown component.otherwise by default the above controller call this component and view and layout .

```
index.php?option=com_dropdown&view=dropdown&layout=edit
```

but my component name is "test" .how I tell to the controller to do not load the "dropdown" component and load the "test" component?

Comment: So you have created com_test and com_dropdown but you want to access com_test from a toolbar inside of com_dropdown?

Comment: Is your end goal to create a custom drop down select you can use anywhere in your code? If so there's an easier way using the framework.